# Discord Python - Tried to make code respond to me as admin based on role, not responding to me at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

*Edit: Posting the whole code so you can get a better context of my problem
Also, the context of what I wanted to achieve is just to make a command that only I can use.
If you're curious about where I got the code from, Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SW6QUMaKGDQ) to the code I was following.*

Original:
So what I'm trying to do is make the discord python bot respond to me as an admin using my role "Streamer"

problem is, not only does it not respond to me as admin, it doesn't respond to me at all. Visual Studio Code does not see any problems in the code so I'm not sure of the cause.

```
    import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        prefix = "syd."
        if message.content.startswith(prefix):
            command = message.content[len(prefix):] #get commands
            isAdmin = [role.name ==
                        "Streamer" for role in message.author.roles][0]

            if command == "hello" and isAdmin:
                await message.channel.send("Hello Syd!")
            
            else:
                discord.utils.get(discord.guild.roles, name='Streamer')
                await message.channel.send("Hi")


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('MTE0MDgwOTg2ODM1ODQ1MTMyMA.GcpAIl.a-b5uNVIce_o3ML2BP3Bgd9vNpUPLcviUZJoAo')
```

What I expect to happen is either
A. Respond to me with "Hello Syd", thus confirming that the admin commands works
or
B. Respond to me with "Hi", thus confirming that the command doesn't work and I need to change it.

Comment: Did you enable and import the `message_content` Intent?

Comment: Yeah, message_content is set to true

`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the monitoring of messages to check for a command, why don't you implement commands from discord.ext module instead?

Below is an example:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intent = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intent)

class MyClient(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_any_role("Streamer")  # Decorator to check if user has role
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello Syd!")

# Load cog
bot.add_cog(MyClient(bot))

# Event: Bot is ready
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")

# Run the bot with your token
bot_token = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE"
bot.run(bot_token)
```

Maybe that works better for your case, and actually improve the code making it easier to define further commands.